# c++ struct with long long bit field

Tags: c++, struct, bit-fields

I have some issue with struct including bit fields. Consider the following code:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct DATA_WARNINGS {
    unsigned char fl_num        : 8;
    unsigned char dev_reload    : 1;
    unsigned char               : 1;
    unsigned long long flags    : 54;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

The size of such structure is 10 bytes as expected. What I would like to do is to fit this structure in 8 bytes without changing the width of the bit fields. So what I did is changed the type of the first field to unsigned long long. Like this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct DATA_WARNINGS {
    unsigned long long fl_num   : 8;
    unsigned char dev_reload    : 1;
    unsigned char               : 1;
    unsigned long long flags    : 54;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

I expected that all structure fit in one unsigned long long. But actually size of such structure became 17 bytes returned by sizeof. If I change all fields type to unsigned long long than structure size becomes 8 bytes.
The question is how to fit structure in 8 bytes without changing fields type to much. I'm using VS2013 on 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when dealing with bit fields, the size/layout is entirely up to the compiler.

The reason for the odd structure sizes is in fact because the underlying type (`unsigned long long` vs `unsigned char`) is different, so the compiler won't try to merge the bit-fields. When they're all `unsigned long long`, the compiler can merge them into a single 8-byte quantity. Thus, there's really no workaround except to change everything to `unsigned long long`.